# jboss 6.x: sending e-Mails if specific type of Exception is thrown

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, alert, jboss6.x

We use jBoss logging and got it finally working - now we have the problem that we dont want to send an e-Mail everytime an ERROR accures. We just want to send an e-Mail if defined Exceptions are thrown. e.g. com.myproject.exceptions.fatal.ProjectFatalException

The default definition in the "jboss-logging.xml" looks like this:

```
   <log4j-appender name="SMTP" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
      <error-manager>
         <only-once/>
      </error-manager>

  <level name="ERROR"/>
  <properties>
     <property name="to">admin@myhost.domain.com</property>
     <property name="from">nobody@myhost.domain.com</property>
     <property name="subject">JBoss Sever Errors</property>
     <property name="SMTPHost">localhost</property>
     <property name="bufferSize">10</property>
  </properties>

  <formatter>
     <pattern-formatter pattern="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"/>
  </formatter>
</log4j-appender>
```

Comment: Have you managed to use custom filters (i.e - ones you developed) with jboss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this answer is almost 3 months late, hopefully this still helps you and others in the future. You can use the `StringMatchFilter` to limit the email to a certain error.

You can solve this problem with a combination of [SMTPAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SMTPAppender.html) and [filters](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/spi/Filter.html). Add the following in your `jboss-log4j.xml`:-

```
<!-- add the SMTPAppender -->
<appender name="SMTP" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender">
     <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
       <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n"/>
     </layout> 
     <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
     <param name="To" value="someone@somewhere.com"/>
     <param name="From" value="someone@somewhere.com"/>
     <param name="Subject" value="JBoss Alert: ProjectFatalException"/>
     <param name="SMTPHost" value="some.smtp.host"/>
     <param name="BufferSize" value="512"/>
     <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
         <param name="LevelMin" value="error" />
         <param name="LevelMax" value="fatal" />
     </filter>
     <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
           <param name="StringToMatch" value="ProjectFatalException" />
           <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
     </filter>
     <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.DenyAllFilter"/>
   </appender> 
    <!-- add the SMTP appender to your project package category -->
    <category name="com.myproject">
         <priority value="ERROR"/>
         <appender-ref ref="SMTP"/>
    </category>
```

As a side note, generally it is a good idea to add slow appenders like SMTP as ASYNC. By default it is synchronous.

Comment: This works but it matches the string only from the message. If the string to be matched is part of the exception then it does not work (verified from the log4j source code too). Do you see any alternatives?